# Failed to open error in libchart library in php

Tags: php

I'm using Libchart library in my project to generate graphs. I'm trying to execute example in libchart but I'm getting following error.

> imagepng(generated/demo1.png): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fileupload\libchart\classes\view\plot\Plot.php on
>   line 284

this is my code

```
include "libchart/classes/libchart.php";
$chart = new VerticalBarChart(500, 250);
$dataSet = new XYDataSet();
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Jan 2005", 273));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Feb 2005", 321));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("March 2005", 442));
$dataSet->addPoint(new Point("April 2005", 711));
$chart->setDataSet($dataSet);
$chart->setTitle("Monthly usage for www.example.com");
$chart->render("generated/demo1.png");
```

when I change the last line of code to `$chart->render();` then it opens binary format in my browser.
Could any one please help me to solve this error?

Comment: Your `getcwd()` is probably not what you think it is, is there a folder named `generated` there & readable for the process?

Comment: yes there is a folder called generated.it is empty folder.

Comment: In your `getcwd()` at that point? Which is?

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fileupload

Comment: So, `C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fileupload\generated` exists and is writable? What happens if you temporarily give `render()` the _full_ path?

Comment: generated file is in "C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fileupload\demo\generated"

Comment: There ya go, so `generated` was _not_ in the current working dir. I'd say `$chart->render("demo/generated/demo1.png");` has a large chance of succeeding.

Comment: I changed to full path as u suggested. This time there is no error but nothing display.

Comment: how do I give write access to demo/generated folder?

Comment: Of course not, it saves it to a file. Do you want it _both_ saved to file _and_ to display? In that case, set the proper headers (`header('Content-type: image/png');` & `readfile('demo/generated/demo1.png');`.

Comment: Thanks now graph is creating in generated folder as demo1.png.but it not displaying in browser.it displays as a smalll icon.its not displaying the chart.i changed code as header('Content-type: image/png'); readfile('demo/generated/demo1.png'); $chart->render("demo/generated/demo1.png");

Comment: @devuser Most likely because an error is causing the image to be broken. Either try to open the png in a text editor or change `Content-type` to `text/html` temporarily.

Comment: changed content-type to text/html and it gives the out put as C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fileupload‰PNG  IHDRôúØÉ" IDATxœíÝ}XWÖðKø)‹b–bD–¢EEª¼)Ò,J-¥T]–Z‹ø]KQÅZ?²VkE¥ÖRj‘¢¥©Z¤,EWy\Ê"[-R‹JQ>$ óþq×i6„ÈÀÀäfÎïñp3NÎœ$'3gn&FE!†EÀuØÅw0@PÜÀ™è¾[¥êÖq¯B©úôËs_ež©ºQþ¨­YX9Œ—¸¿õékÁ^¦&ÆO|xccøtöéž-££¸§¤çÇoú ­ùºú ¹¥½Åˆ1FÈÈÖnlâúÈàŸÕýðPÜ`0©ªªZ½zusss``àŒ3<ˆ222Šˆˆ8yò¤ÆøÑ£G'L˜°lÙ2GY¼x±««kFFB( àáÃ‡ííí³gÏîwØ ?ºçn;vúÍŸâÁµ›Ž>ø>Õ  .......

Comment: @devuser There should be no `C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fileupload` in the output of the image.

Comment: yes that is true.i'm wondering how it comes.when I inspect the elements img src is look like this "<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost/test/fileupload/uploadFile.php?type=1"> img src refers to the link in my form action.i cant understand how it happens.could you please help me to solve this?

Comment: @devuser It has nothing to do with your img element. Somehow the code that reads `demo/generated/demo1.png` also echos `C:\xampp\htdocs\test\fileupload`. Without the complete code, including the changes you made, it would be impossible for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
this is my complete code
<?php
include "libchart/classes/libchart.php";

class fileupload
{

  var $htmlID_type = "type";
  var $type_uploadfile = 0;
  var $type_generategraphs = 1;
  var $content_html = "";


    function __construct()
    {
        $this->__switch();
        $this->__print();
    }

  function __switch()
 {


    enter code here
        $this->param_type = $this->getParamType();

        switch ($this->param_type)
        {`enter code here`
            case $this->type_uploadfile :
                $this->selectFileUplaod ();
                break;

            case $this->type_generategraphs :
                $this->generateGraphs();
                break;

        }

    }

    function __print()
    {
        print <<<HEREDOC

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <head>
                    <style>
                    body{
                      margin-left:20%;
                      margin-right:20%;
                      margin-top:50px;
                     }
                     table, td, th
                     {
                         border:1px solid black;
                      }
                     th
                       {
                          background-color:#00BFFF;
                          color:white;
                           }
                     </style>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        {$this->content_html}
                    </body>

                    </html>



HEREDOC;
    }

  function getParamType()
    {
        if (isset ( $_GET [$this->htmlID_type] ))
        {
            return $_GET [$this->htmlID_type];
        } 
        else
            return $this->type_uploadfile;
    }



    function selectFileUplaod()
    {

       $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");
      // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {
               echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }

        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT 
              income_id,
              month,
              paint_cost,
              parts_cost,
              repair_cost,
              excess_Suspense,
              sublet,
              remove_refit_cost
              FROM income");
        echo "<h3>Bundamba Income</h3>";
        echo "<table>
         <tr>
         <th>Paint</th>
         <th>Parts</th>
         <th>Remove Refit Cost</th>
         <th>Repair</th>
         <th>Excess Suspense</th>
         <th>Sublet</th>
        </tr>";

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td width=100>" . $row['paint_cost'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width=100>" . $row['parts_cost'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width=100>" . $row['remove_refit_cost'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td width=100>" . $row['repair_cost'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td width=100>" . $row['excess_Suspense'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td width=100>" . $row['sublet'] . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
      echo "<br>";
      $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT  
              cost_of_saleID ,  paint_liquid ,  
              paint_consumables,  
              workshop_consumables,
              parts_purchased,
              wages_paintshop,
              wages_workshop,
              suplier_discount,
              sublet_cost 
              FROM  cost_of_sale 
                LIMIT 0 , 30");
        echo "<h3>Bundamba cost of sale</h3>";
        echo "<table>
         <tr>
         <th>Paint Consumables</th>
         <th>Paint Liquid</th>
          <th>Parts Purchased</th>
          <th>Workshop Consumables</th>
          <th>Wages - Paintshop</th>
          <th>Wages - Workshop</th>
          <th>Supplier Discounts</th>
          <th>Sublets Costs</th>
        </tr>";

      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1))
      {
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['paint_consumables'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['paint_liquid'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['parts_purchased'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['workshop_consumables'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['wages_paintshop'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['wages_workshop'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['suplier_discount'] . "</td>";
       echo "<td>" . $row['sublet_cost'] . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
      }
      echo "</table>";
    $this->content_html = <<<End_Of_String

            <FORM action="uploadFile.php?{$this->htmlID_type}={$this->type_generategraphs}" method="POST" />
             <input type="submit" value="Income vs Cost" style="margin-top:20px">
             <input type="submit" value="Income vs Cost Ratio" style="margin-top:20px">
            </FORM> 


End_Of_String;


   // mysqli_close($con);


}   

    function generateGraphs()
    {
        echo  getcwd();
        print "rrrrr";
       header("Content-type:image/png");    

       $chart = new VerticalBarChart(500, 250);

       $dataSet = new XYDataSet();
       $dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Jan 2005", 273));
       $dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Feb 2005", 321));
       $dataSet->addPoint(new Point("March 2005", 442));
       $dataSet->addPoint(new Point("April 2005", 711));
       $chart->setDataSet($dataSet);
       $chart->setTitle("Monthly usage for www.example.com");


        $chart->render("demo/generated/demo1.png");
        readfile("demo/generated/demo1.png");


       // $im = imagecreatefrompng("demo/generated/demo1.png");
       // header('Content-Type: image/png');
       //imagepng($im);
       //imagedestroy($im);

    }   


}


$obj = new fileupload();
?>
```

Comment: You shouldn't post an edit as an answer! Anyhow your echoing `getcwd()` and `rrrrr` in `generateGraphs()` and that what's screwing up your png image output.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error now when trying to plot the piechart using LibChart library.  The problem is that you would not have created a folder named 'generated' in your current folder.. but the name given for the image is generated/demo1.png which says that generated is a folder containing the file "demo1.png". So, just give 'demo1.png' instead of 'generated/demo1.png' and try running the snippet.. I got the output just now!!